# how to make 'customized' view in XamarinForms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I started develop Xamarin Forms app half month ago.
Now I want and need to know how to make customize view
(for data grid, drawing graph etc, forexample components providing tools for grid or graph...)

but I don't know how, where i can reference...
is there any document or book or anything?? explaining the procedure or ways

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating custom views in Xamarin is fairly easy by using inheritance. Also almost all of the assumptions and patterns from WPF work in Xamarin as well.

There is a very good free ebook in Xamarin forms that helped me a lot. You can find it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize grids and graphics, Xamarin.Forms per se won´t help you a lot. You need to extend Xamarin.Forms components implementing platform code with [custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).

If your app has many data components like [data-grids](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/datagrid) and [charts](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/chart), I would suggest to take a look at 3erd party libraries like [SyncFusion](https://blog.xamarin.com/visualize-your-data-with-charts-graphs-and-xamarin-forms/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui).